# Seemless Transition of a Split Access Database when Network Connectivity is Lost

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Database that operates split (Front end and Back End).

Front End is located on the desktop of a workstation (in this case, a tablet PC), and communicates with the Backend that is located on a Mapped Network Drive.

I know how to procedurally use VBA modules to sever the connection and to restore the connection requiring manual input from a user.

How do I code a Module to monitor for Network Connectivity Loss (ie: Mapped Drive goes offline for some reason), and still allow the User to access the database and add records locally, and when the network connection becomes available again, relink to the backend and add data to the backend tables that was entered while disconnected without losing data that was added to the database when disconnected from the Backend?

I Haven't tried anything yet, because I can't find any information that is close to what I am looking to accomplish.

Comment: This sounds tricky! IMHO you should by default save the user input on the front end especially if it is a tablet and then give the user a button - "I have finished, update the database" so that it is clear what is happening (or not as the case may be!).